# Htaccess redirect to index and remove trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I can't seem to get it to work in my scenario.. So basically when a user goes to http://www.example.com/contact the index.php should be loaded, but the url shouldn't be changed, the correct content will be loaded via javascript. This is working fine now, and my htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem however now is that when a user visits http://www.example.com/contact he gets redirected to http://www.example.com/contact/ and I can't seem to be able to remove the trailing slash..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No it's not. There's only the index.php and javascript checking url path.

Comment: First request is http://local.mind.nl/contact and gives me a 301 status, then it does a request to http://local.mind.nl/contact/ (with trailing slash) which has a 200 status.

Comment: And you can see that `301` redirect is happening here to add a trailing slash. If there is no rule doing so in .htaccess or Apache config then check your code.

Comment: But isn't the htaccess causing the redirect? Meaning there is something wrong with the htacess that I posted above?

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll try something else then. Thanks!

Comment: Errm, I think some comments have been deleted (comments that contain questions I was about to ask)? Is `/contact` a directory? I think from your response that "No it's not". There is no code in the `.htaccess` file posted that would trigger this redirect (or any 3xx redirect for that matter). The redirect must be getting triggered from the server-side code (eg. `index.php`)...? JavaScript can't trigger a 3xx redirect.